# Graph API User delta query not returning Manager following a change to the user

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

When I run this initial query:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$select=id,displayName,manager,jobTitle&$filter=id+eq+'87fa2ed7-5e58-4ff5-85ca-42a973e103e7'](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$select=id,displayName,manager,jobTitle&$filter=id+eq+%2787fa2ed7-5e58-4ff5-85ca-42a973e103e7%27)

I get the following response (as expected):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(id,displayName,jobTitle,manager)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=<removed>",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "Jane Doe",
            "jobTitle": "Super Administrator",
            "id": "87fa2ed7-5e58-4ff5-85ca-42a973e103e7",
            "manager@delta": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "1ab00b74-6f7e-45ca-8629-22d64632501d"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I follow the @odata.nextLink URL, which returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$deltatoken=<removed>",
    "value": []
}
```

I don't really understand why it doesn't just give me the deltaLink in the first call, but that isn't the issue. At this point, I make a change to the user's job title in Azure AD (outside of Graph API) and then follow the @odata.deltaLink, which returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$deltatoken=<removed>",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "Jane Doe",
            "jobTitle": "Administrator",
            "id": "87fa2ed7-5e58-4ff5-85ca-42a973e103e7"
        }
    ]
}
```

No manager!!

The only attribute changed was the job title; Manager is unchanged. This behavior is the same in both the v1.0 and beta endpoints. Also, I am not using the "prefer:return=minimal" header (or any additional headers for that matter).

Can anyone provide some insight into this?

Comment: Probably a bug in Graph API. I can reproduce the same behavior with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$select=id,displayName,manager,jobTitle&$filter=id+eq+'{user_id}'` but if `displayName` is not selected then `@odata.deltaLink` works fine and returns manager `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$select=id,manager,jobTitle&$filter=id+eq+'{user_id}'`

Comment: I can't replicate that. For me, manager is never returned when using the @odata.deltaLink, with or without displayName being selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the confusion. The expectation is that if you do not add the minimal headers, that all properties of the object will be returned.

If you add prefer:return=minimal header, the API will only return the changed properties of an object.

*But* if you omit these headers, it does not imply that the API will return all properties of the object.

If the header is omitted, the odata.deltaLink will return all direct properties of an object, but will generally return linked properties unless the linked property has also changed.

Linked properties include things like Manager, or GroupMember.

Comment: The issue is that the manager attribute is returned on the initial query, but not in any subsequent queries using the @odata.deltaLink, even though the "manager" attribute was specifically requested in the initial query.